# Excel user defined formula that references dynamic cell

Tags: excel, function, user-defined-functions

I have a translation formula that references a different list of barcodes and Names. The formula looks up the barcode and replaces the German/French with English. I want to make this into a User defined formula but when I do this the formula only works for the defined cell and copies that cell result to all cells. How can I make this function so it references the highlighted cell?

[image: what translation looks like without user defined formula]

My attempt at formula

=INDEX(('\server1\shared\DOCUMENTS\AMAZON[Index of barcode to title.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$1:$B$781),MATCH(A3,('\server1\shared\DOCUMENTS\AMAZON[Index of barcode to title.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1:$A$781),0))

When I use the formula in the userdefined formula it does not reference the adjacent cell but the cell I used to make the formula.

What I am trying to achieve but I cannot figure out how to change the MATCH(A3 part into the selectable cell.

[image: what I want my formula to do]